# how can I append another button when everytime someone puts antoher model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to append a new button everytime someone adds a new data for a make from a car. However it just keeps adding to the same button. How can do it to a new button per data?

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET'
  url: '/cars/'+ year + '/' + make_id,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var model = data
    $('div#render-cars').append('<button id="car-model">' + model +  '</button>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML or a test case to work with?

Comment: you're problem might be with the id, if you use a select $(id), it will only pickup the first one.  Try to be creative and see if you can generate a unique id for each.

Comment: Thanks ! I am going to try that

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code. Same ID cannot be duplicate. use class instead or use dynamic ID

```
$.ajax({
             method: 'GET'
             url: '/cars/'+ year + '/' + make_id,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data){
                var model = data

                $('div#render-cars').append('<button class="car-model">' + model +  '</button>');
```

Comment: Although id can't be duplicate, browsers will still allow you to add multiple elements with same id. It will not keep adding the same element over and over again as mentioned in the question.

Comment: actually I noticed also is because it was an array so I had to iterate over.